# How to create a custom post type for a video with a link

Tags: php, wordpress

I have custom post types for videos on my site. They are displayed on the pages in the form of cards. One post is a picture, a title for a video card, and a link. When you click on the card, a popup with a video should open. I display video cards using the WP_Query loop. My problem is that I don't know how to link to the video. The post does not have a single page. I need to somehow specify a link to it when creating a post and display it. How can i do this?

```js
<?php $video_link = get_field('video_link'); ?>
<?php             
     $case = new WP_Query( array(
      'post_type' => 'videos',
       'paged' => -1,
                   'order'  => 'DESC',
                    ) );      
                    while ( $case->have_posts() ) : $case->the_post(); ?>  
                   <?php $cur_terms = get_the_terms( $case->post->ID, 'categories' ); ?>
             <li class="portfolio-section__item __js_masonry-item>
              <a class="project-preview project-preview--elastic" data-fancybox href="<?php echo $video_link ?>">
                <span class="project-preview__image">
                  <img src="<? the_post_thumbnail_url() ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
             <span class="hover-button"> 
                  <svg width="17" height="19">
                    <use xlink:href="#triangle"></use>
                  </svg>
                </span>
                </span>
                <span class="project-preview__bottom">
                  <span class="project-preview__title"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
                  <span class="project-preview__icon">
                    <svg width="24" height="23">
                      <use xlink:href="#link-arrow2"></use>
                    </svg>
                  </span>
                </span>
              </a>
            </li>
            <?php endwhile;
            $case->reset_postdata();  ?>
```

Comment: just use the built in custom fields. More info here https://wordpress.org/support/article/custom-fields/ and  https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/wordpress-custom-fields-101-tips-tricks-and-hacks/#customfieldsintro .

Comment: As mentioned above, this is certainly the simplest method. However, not the most elegant. The custom fields section can scare some people despite how benign it is.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would probably simply add the link in the content of the custom post type, from what I see you are not using it. Or you could also add it as an excerpt.

Or like Cornel said, use the built in custom fields. More info here wordpress.org/support/article/custom-fields

Last solution is to use ACF plugin (Advanced Custom Fields) and just create a custom field for the link of the video.

Hope this helps

Comment: There are built-in custom fields that can be used. No need for a plugin for one field.

Comment: That's true Cornel. I am so used to ACF that I forgot that there is a built-in option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I use ACF on my site. But the problem is that when I select "Show this field group if" and select Post Type "Video", then I have a link field. But when I display on the main card and display this field, it is not displayed

Comment: I think the problem is that I choose to display the field for Custom post types "Video" and the field is not displayed on the main page where I display video cards

Comment: It should not be a problem cause you query the video and you can display the title and the picture. So normally, after your query when you do $videoLink = get_field('theNameOfYourField'); you should have your link.

Comment: Yes, I do. I added the code for how I display, but I get an empty href attribute

Comment: That's what i thought, you need to use this line $video_link = get_field('video_link'); inside your while loop

Comment: while ( $case->have_posts() ) : $case->the_post(); 
$video_link = get_field('video_link');
print_r($video_link);
?>
You should see your link

Comment: Installing an entire plugin to add a field sounds a bit crazy to me. Can't you code the field yourself? Why would you add so much overhead and maintenance for something so little.

Answer (score -1):

The built-in custom fields method would be the quickest and simplest, but not the most elegant.

Here is a more elegant method of adding a custom metabox and a field.

```
// Hook a new metabox
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'add_custom_box' );
function add_custom_box() {
    $screens = [ 'videos' ];
    foreach ( $screens as $screen ) {
        add_meta_box(
            'unique_box_identifier',     // Unique ID
            'Custom Meta Box Title',     // Box title
            'custom_box_html',           // Content callback, this calls the markup function below
            $screen                      // Post type
        );
    }
}

// Field Markup
function custom_box_html( $post ) {
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'video_link', true );
    
    ?>

    <label for="video_link">Link URL: </label>
    <input type="url" name="video_link" id="video_link" value="<?php if (isset($value)) { echo $value; } ?>" />

    <?php
}

// Save the metadata with the post
add_action( 'save_post', 'save_postdata' );
function save_postdata( $post_id ) {
    if ( array_key_exists( 'video_link', $_POST ) ) {
        update_post_meta(
            $post_id,
            'video_link',
            $_POST['video_link']
        );
    }
}
```

Then to get the value for use in your template, just call like this:

```
$value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'video_link', true );
echo $value;
```

Source Docs:

- https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/metadata/custom-meta-boxes/
- https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/